# Creating a Model::create dynamically using call_user_func_array gives an error on Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following code to create an entry in the database:

`$element_names_array = explode(',', $request->input('element_names'));
        foreach ($element_names_array as $element)
        {
            $data[$element] = $request->input($element);
        }
        $model = '\\App\\' . $request->input('connected_model');
        return call_user_func_array($model . '::create', $data);`

An array is created and passed onto the call_user_func_array function, which triggers the `Model::create()` method passing the array as an argument.

But, for some reason, right after the `call_user_func_array()` the array type gets converted to string type.

I'm getting this error and error log:

`Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create() must be of the type array, string given`

Error log

`in Model.php line 570
at Model::create('R200500002', 'MALSKDJSNAM123123')
at call_user_func_array('\App\RepairOrder::create', array('ro_number' => 'R200500002', 'vin_number' => 'MALSKDJSNAM123123')) in GdmsBotTask.php line 26`

As you can notice, an array is passed to the call_user_func_array... but it gets converted to string. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call_user_func_array` converts the array into individual parameters.

To fix, use `call_user_func` or wrap `$data` in a parent array:

```
return call_user_func($model . '::create', $data)
return call_user_func_array($model . '::create', [$data])
```

As a side note, unless this code is only callable by highly trusted authenticated users, then you have a huge security problem

Comment: This code is only used by a single user... That too a BOT script. No worries. But definitely please point out the security flaw...

Comment: @notANerdDev Well you are building code from user input, so it is possible for a malicious individual to craft a post request that creates a new record for any model in your code, eg users, discounts, transactions etc (i have no idea what your database holds, so i picked some scary sounding ones!)

Comment: Oh ya!! Lol... i see that... i kinda knew that.. but again... it's a bot using the app... so.. no worries.